# Entity Framework not returns duplicate matching items

Tags: c#

I found an interesting issue in Entity Framework. Check the code bellow. Here i am using `Contains()` to find all matching `Id` rows from Table `Test1` but when i add same id multiple times it returns only 1 item not duplicating items but i want to get duplicate items too. How can i do this then?

```
var ids = new List<int>();
                ids.Add(1);
                ids.Add(1);
var foo = ctx.Test1.Include("Test2").Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

Comment: If find this unlikely. How are you proving this to yourself? Are you sure you are pointing at the right database?

Comment: It is absolutely not unlikely. It is how ef core and sql have worked since inception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can not. You really need to learn the basic of how SQL works and how query works because your question is a fundamental misunderstanding.

> when i add same id multiple times it returns only 1 item not duplicating items

Because the table STILL contains only 1 item. if you add the same ID multiple times, why would you expect it to return the row multiple times?

The way it is evaluated is:

- Take row
- Check whether the ID matches any of the provided list.
- Next row.

So, regardless how often you put the ID into the list of approved id's, it OBVIOUSLY will only return one row. You do not get duplicate items because you do not have duplicate items to start with.

Like so often when using anything Ef related, it also helps to intercept and look at the generated SQL and the generated query plan - this at least will make obviously clear that you can not get 2 id's. Contains will be an IN clause, containing the list of values. Like I said above, contains checks for rows, it will not magically duplicate them.

I would suggest making the duplication manually after query - though in 25 years I have never seen this requirement coming up, so I would strongly suggest you check whether what you try to do makes any logical sense from a higher perspective first.

Answer (score 1):

Why should it be the other way? Your EF `Contains` instruction has in SQL "IN" form:

```
SELECT 
...
FROM ...
WHERE ... IN (1, 1)
```